# Getting simpleName() after getClass() in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin

In java, I am able to use getClass() and then retrieve simpleName from that class object without any issues.

```
String tag = someObject.getClass().getSimpleName(); // java code
```

But when converting to Kotlin, this causes warnings

> Call uses reflection API which is not found in compilation classpath.
>   Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath

The kotlin code is

```
someObject::class.simpleName!! // kotlin code
```

What is the proper way of avoiding

> kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError ? Needs additional
>   dependency to kotlin-reflect.jar. Maybe would be better use
>   ::class.java.simpleName

Comment: Why not use the alternative recommended in the error? `someObject::class.java.simpleName`

Comment: I am new to Kotlin, so was unaware. Also, I just tried it and I am receiving "unresolved reference: java". EDIT: Clean project cleared that up! Can you add as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `someObject::class.java.simpleName`.

Answer (score 8):

There is couple ways to do this in Kotlin
You can receive the name via property - *KClass.qualifiedName*

```
val name = AClass::class.qualifiedName;
```

or through the *Class.getName*

```
val name = AClass::class.java.getName();
```

or you can try with *Class.name*

```
val name = AClass::class.java.name;
```

or *Class.canonicalName*

```
var name = AClass::class.java.canonicalName as String
```

Comment: None of those seem to quite line up with `simpleName`, though. They all are for the canonical name.

Comment: @CommonsWare solution is correct. Thanks for your response Edgar. I'm sure you addressed some other concerns from others who are learning Kotlin and following along and reading this thread.

Answer (score 5):

Lot of answers ask you to enter type your class name, well I have the shortest solution for you.

```
javaClass.simpleName
```

You can use the above line anywhere to get the class name, it will return your current class name.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are in the same class or activity, then to get the name of the activity or class you can call.

```
this::class.simpleName
```

Let's say your activity/class name is `LoginActivityV2` then you can also use

`this@LoginActivityV2::class.simplename`